# How do I get boost::spirit to stop parsing at keyword?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I want to parse input like "start  abc end" to extract "abc".

Here's my test code:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <ostream>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    typedef std::string::const_iterator iterator;

    qi::rule<iterator, std::string(), qi::space_type> rule =
        "start" >>
        qi::lexeme[+qi::char_] >>
        "end";

    std::string input("start  abc end");
    auto iter = input.begin();
    std::string result;
    qi::phrase_parse(iter, input.end(), rule, qi::space, result);

    std::cout << "Result:   " << result   << std::endl;
}
```

The output is "Result: abc end".

Comment: Note that if you were to check the result of `qi::phrase_parse` you would see that the parsing failed.

Comment: I noticed that and assumed because "end" was consumed early, the parser could not complete the match.

Comment: I couldn't compile your code, which version of boost are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is, you expect your parser to stop at whitespace or the keyword "end". But your parser basically accepts any character after "start" keyword.

```
+char_
```

Above parser means: any character sequence longer than 1 (including whitespace).

Somehow you have to tell your parser to stop at whitespace or "end" keyword. For example below parser will accept characters until "end" keyword

```
+(char_ - lit("end"))
```

I suggest you to have a look at the list of parsers in spirit documentation. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/quick_reference/qi_parsers.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't help.  Changing the rule to

 qi::rule<iterator, std::string(), qi::space_type> rule =
  "start" >>
  qi::lexeme[+qi::char_] - qi::lit("end") >>
  "end";

produced the same result.

Comment: I believe it should be like this `"start" >> qi::lexeme[+qi::char_ - qi::lit("end")]  >> "end"`

Comment: That's a permutation I haven't tried yet, but it didn't help.  Got any more?

Comment: +(qi::char_ - qi::lit("end")) is a solution

Comment: That worked!  You were close @HeyYO.  If you edit your answer, I'll accept it.